# Wrong value for variable at dd()

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to get comment for my articles ( edit article ).I made variable `$event_comm` in `EventController` but when I'm trying to get value this return [].Can you tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix that?. My table `event_comment` has columns `id`, `user_id`, `event_id`, `comments`, where is comments for every article.

**dd($event_comm)**

```
Collection {#823 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => EventComment {#824 ▼
      #table: "event_comments"
      #fillable: array:3 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:1 [▼
        "comments" => "Comment1"
      ]
      #original: array:1 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => EventComment {#826 ▶}
    2 => EventComment {#825 ▶}
    3 => EventComment {#812 ▶}
    4 => EventComment {#811 ▶}
    5 => EventComment {#810 ▶}
    6 => EventComment {#809 ▶}
    7 => EventComment {#808 ▶}
  ]
}
```

** EventComment.php Eloquent**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EventComment extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'event_comments';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'event_id','comments'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event','event_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$article = \DB::table("events")
    ->where("id", $id)
    ->select("id", "subject", "information", "public", "category_id", "event_type_id", "country", "address", "city", "starts", "ends", "organizer", "website", "email", "telephone")
    ->first();
         $data['article'] = $article;
$event_comm = EventComment::where('comments', '=', 'user_id')->get();

dd($event_comm);

return view("admin.editEvent", $data)
    ->with(compact('event_comm'));
```

Comment: You are passing 'user_id' as a string to your query. Not as variable. That's probably where it goes wrong

Comment: Maybe do you know how to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean `comments = user_id`? they're both column right?

Comment: It should be `EventComment::where('comments', '=', $id)->get();`

Comment: `EventComment::where('comments', '=', $id)->get();` doesn;t work, same problem :(.  `comments = user_id`, yes, they are both columns

Comment: Do you have $user_id variable ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to query?

Comment: then you should not do a `where('comments', '=', 'user_id')` what do you want to do to it exactly? do you just want to get all the data on that table or you have a where condition for user_id and event_id?

Comment: I dont have $user_id as variable.I guess that I can use `user_id` column from my database

Comment: What is your where condition ? Please describe fully

Comment: what do you mean? they're but column right ? so its imposible. Do you have user table? you can query that first and then get the id there for your user_id

Comment: be clear first on what you want to do so that we can help you

Comment: Your sound look like that you dont know what are you wanted to do >>>

Comment: I have on my website all articles from table `events`, but here isn't comments.They're in `event_comments`. Here is 2 photos for that. https://imgur.com/a/x5fP154 . With `$event_comm = EventComment::select('comments')->get();` I've got  an array with all comments from database ( 8 ) . How can I receive comment for `event_id`?

Comment: @AndreiNagy im still confused but I answer it. See if it can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receive comment based on events id
since you already have article do this one

`$event_comm = EventComment::where('event_id', $article->id)->get();`

or just simply

`$event_comm = EventComment::where('event_id', $id)->get();`

since you are already passing $id in your controller

if you want to get only the comment in query.

`$event_comm = EventComment::where('event_id', $id)->select('comments')->get();`

Comment: This is working partial. Now I'm getting `[{"id":13,"user_id":"542","event_id":"1806","comments":"testul meu :)","created_at":"2019-07-09 06:04:26","updated_at":"2019-07-09 06:04:26"}] ` . How can I only pick "comments" ?

Comment: `$event_comm->comments` but you need to use `foreach($event_comm as $comm)` then call it as `$comm->comment` you need to foreach it because its an collection or an array.

Comment: You are welcome! Next time just be clear so we can help you more faster

Comment: Now, if I want to get name of users how can do that? Because I have `user_id` of every user who post a comment? To be like... `Comment by  ....  : $comm->comments` . The name of users is on table `users`, column `name`.

Comment: then you need to get also the `user_id` column and that's another query or you can use join

Comment: `->join('event_comments', 'event_comments.user_id', '=', 'users.name')` something like that?

Comment: No. I assume your user table is users then add this one `->join('users', 'event_comments.user_id', '=', 'users.id')` then change your select as `->select('event_comments.comments', 'user.name')`

Comment: Bro, I tried this method: `$event_user = \App\EventComment::with('user', 'event')->get();`. Now I get all comments array with this for everyone : https://imgur.com/a/SUvpAzG, under id I have username of user who made the comment.How to pick it from this array?

Comment: `$event_user->user->username` or `$event_user->user()->username` but you still need to foreach the $event_user

Comment: This works : `{{$evnt->user->username }}`, but now I get `Comment by devpe Comment by Matei Bogdan Stefan Comment by Test andrei45  
Comment by sonali Comment by devpe  etc` . Can I only get name of user who commented? Because now I get all data for all comments ( 9 array) and that's why I get all these comment by...

Comment: Are you still using the $event_comm? you can use the $event_user for everything tho. for the comments, events and users. Just explore it more. You can read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) so you can understand it more

Comment: I used this : ` @foreach($event_user as $evnt)
<label class="label">Comment by {{$evnt->user->username }}</label>
 @endforeach`  but with $event_user I've got all comments, now only 2 like $event_comm.

Comment: that because you didn't use `where('event_id', $id)`

Comment: Do you know why I get  the name twice? `Comment by Matei Bogdan Stefan
Comment by Test andrei45  
testul meu :)
Comment by Matei Bogdan Stefan
Comment by Test andrei45  
inca un test
`  Here is my code in view : `@foreach($event_comm as $comm)
         @foreach($event_user as $evnt)
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">  
         <label class="label">Comment by {{$evnt->user->username }}</label>
          @endforeach
         <label class="input">
          {{ Form::text('subject', $comm->comments) }}
         </label>
        </div>
        @endforeach`

Comment: that's because you have two foreach like you can remove the $event_comm and just use $event_user

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function event(Request $request){
              $comments = $request->comments;
              $event_comm = EventComment::with('event')->where('comments', $comments)->get();

    }
try once this
```

Comment: This will not get relative comment of event ! Will get all same comment